# Changing color of layer in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have a layer loaded in QGIS and I would like to change the color. I've seen some code but for the previous versions and they don't work in QGIS 3.4.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to provide the code you tried (along with a link to the source).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute the following code :

```
# My layer
layer = iface.activeLayer() 
# The color
layer.renderer().symbol().setColor(QColor("blue")) 
# Refresh the color on canvas 
layer.triggerRepaint() 
# Refresh the color in layer tree
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```